# What is the algorithm behind re.finditer?

Tags: algorithm, pattern-matching, python-re

I was looking into string searching algorithms and after a few timeits, I found that the re.finditer function had way faster results as compared to my implementation of Naive/KMP/Boyer-Moore. I read that the Python re libray uses a basic backtracking algorithm but I was wondering if someone could point me in a more specific direction/ code where I can try to understand their algorithm better? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

Assuming you're referring to CPython.

The function is defined here:
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/re.py#L243-L248

Backtracking algorithm is implemented here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/sre_compile.py